# Pagination on custom post type not working if permalinks set to rewrite url

Tags: pagination

When rewriting the url like this: .../%postname%/

This is the relevant part of my post type registration arguments:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'haendler', 'with_front' => false )
```

My pagination on the custom post type does not work.

The pagination is there but when I click on page two the link `http://www.example.com/%postname%/page/2` always changes back to `http://www.example.com/%postname%/`

If I disable permalinks to the default querystring style pagination is fine.

What can be the reason for the url automatically removing the `page/2` value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you setup `rewrite` argument when registering your custom post type

Comment: `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'haendler', 'with_front' => false ),`

THis is the argument from the register_post_type function. :/

Comment: Set it to true and see what happen

Answer (score 5):

This issue was reported here : https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15551

It comes from the `redirect_canonical()` WP function.

Try to disable canonical redirect for your custom post type to get pagination work  :

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical','custom_disable_redirect_canonical' ); 
function custom_disable_redirect_canonical( $redirect_url ){
    if ( is_singular('your_custom_post_type') ) $redirect_url = false;
    return $redirect_url;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow you are a genius! Thanks for existing!!!! That totally solved it :-D

Comment: You're welcome, glad you found it useful. If the answer solved your problem, you can mark as accepted :)

Comment: I found this solution after 2 days of search.
It was working on local with MAMP, but not online on OVH's french server, really weird.
Thank for your answer, it saved me.
I think this function is close to a server configuration.. no ?